# i18next not working correctly on ejs

Tags: express, ejs, i18next

Well i created an isolated an simple project to test it (code snnipets bellow) because i was having exactly the same problem in the main project so i thought maybe one of the other components could cause this problem, but i had the same problem in the isolated project and now i don't know how to make it work.
The initialization an the configuration are like this:

```
i18n.init({
    ns: {
        namespaces: ['ns.common', 'ns.special'],
        defaultNs: 'ns.special'
    },
    resSetPath: 'locales/__lng__/new.__ns__.json',
    saveMissing: true,
    debug: true,
    sendMissingTo: 'fallback',
    preload: ['en', 'de'],
    detectLngFromPath: 0,
    ignoreRoutes: ['img/', 'img', 'img/', '/img/', 'css/', 'i18next/']
});

// Configuration
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(i18n.handle); // have i18n befor app.router

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname);

i18n.registerAppHelper(app)
    .serveClientScript(app)
    .serveDynamicResources(app)
    .serveMissingKeyRoute(app);

i18n.serveWebTranslate(app, {
    i18nextWTOptions: {
        languages: ['de-DE', 'en-US', 'dev'],
        namespaces: ['ns.common', 'ns.special'],
        resGetPath: "locales/resources.json?lng=__lng__&ns=__ns__",
        resChangePath: 'locales/change/__lng__/__ns__',
        resRemovePath: 'locales/remove/__lng__/__ns__',
        fallbackLng: "dev",
        dynamicLoad: true
    }
});
```

the ejs is like this:
`html
    <body>
        <span>Should show a hello world</span></br>
        <span>;<%t('hello.world')%></span>
    </body>`

and i added the t function like this (correcting the t not defined error):

```
app.locals.t = function(key){
    return i18n.t(key);
};
```

everything should show the next view on the website:

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2654171/7738735/bef1a7ce-ff25-11e4-89f8-257502b27396.PNG

but instead of that it just shows this:

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2654171/7738741/d0685f84-ff25-11e4-9c3d-1a39ca7c1bb1.PNG

I would really appreciate some advises or an example of ejs using the i18n.
By the way i'm using:
-express 4
-ejs 1
-i18next 1.7.10

Answer (score 1):

in order to solve this problem you have to put the code like this:

```
<span>;<%=t('hello.world')%></span>
```